# With Omniauth, How to record all requests for authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

with omniauth in my app, to have a user use Google oAuth2 to authenticate I redirect the user to:

```
/users/auth/google_oauth2
```

If the users approves the request, then the AuthenticationsController#create is called.

With AuthenticationsController#create - I can add event tracking to record the # of users who approve google auth. What I don't have is the number that I sent to approve meaning I don't have a conversion rate.

How can I track the # of people who hit the URL around making requests to connect.

Answer (score 0):

A nasty solution would be to build a filter around the method Strategy#request_call and do the tracking there.

Inside an initializer:

```
OmniAuth::Strategy.class_eval do
  def request_call_with_tracking
    log :info, "Im running before the actual request_call"
    Tracker.hit(name) #name will return the provider
    request_call_without_tracking
  end
  alias_method_chain :request_call, :tracking
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the OmniAuth setup phase. You can pass a `:setup` option to an OmniAuth provider, with a proc which will be executed before the authentication is performed. You can add event tracking inside this proc.

So if you have some tracker class, you can do this:

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_KEY'], ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET'],
    :setup => lambda { |env|
      Tracker.track
    }
end
```

For more information check out [Avdi Grimm's great blog post about the subject](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/12/20/fancy-github-authentication-with-omniauth/).